# Unable to manual trigger my Azure Timer Trigger using httpclient post request

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

[image]

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-manually-run-non-http

I am trying to manual trigger my Azure Timer function App created in 2.0 and developed in .net core 2.0.

When I try to hit the url I get 403 error.

apikey I pass is picked from :
[image]

Comment: On screen you have my key here and commented key in same line. Which key are you sending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the article you provided, you need to use `_master key` under `Manage` and `Host key`
[image]

Comment: I tried _master key this time. But now I get 400 bad request error.@JoeyCai

Comment: @knowdotnet, Because the request content is json format. So, you need to change `string content = string.Empty;` to `string content = "{}";` and it will work fine:)

Comment: _master and "{}" as content worked. Marked your reply as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use the following class in my integration tests against service bus triggered Azure Functions.

```
 class AzureFunctionCaller
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly string _functionUri;

    public AzureFunctionCaller(string functionName)
    {
        _httpClient = new HttpClient();

        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-functions-key","<Key>");
        _functionUri = $"<FUNCTION_ENDPOINT>/admin/functions/{functionName}";
    }

    public async Task CallViaAdminEndpoint(string content)
    {
        var httpContent = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(_functionUri, httpContent);

        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine($"Response content: {responseContent}");
    }
}
```

Then you must send the data in a format where you place the content in "input" object.

```
 var azureFunctionCaller = new AzureFunctionCaller("<FunctionName>");
 var obj = new
        {
            ... // properties you want to send
        };
        var jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            input = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj)
        });
 await azureFunctionCaller.CallViaAdminEndpoint(jsonContent);`
```

To explain the input property, here is how the same call looks like in postman:

[image]